# PointerPressed: left or right button?

Tags: c#, windows-8, microsoft-metro

How can I get the type of pressed pointer (left mouse down or right mouse down) in a Metro style C# app? I didn't find a `MouseLeftButtonDown`  event handler in any Metro style UI element. I should use `PointerPressed` event instead, but I don't know how can i get which button was pressed.

Comment: There is sample code [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.uielement.pointerpressed)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

PointerPressed is enough to handle mouse buttons:

```
void MainPage_PointerPressed(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // Check for input device
    if (e.Pointer.PointerDeviceType == Windows.Devices.Input.PointerDeviceType.Mouse)
    {
        var properties = e.GetCurrentPoint(this).Properties;
        if (properties.IsLeftButtonPressed)
        {
            // Left button pressed
        }
        else if (properties.IsRightButtonPressed)
        {
            // Right button pressed
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I have a UWP app and when adding a handler to a `MousePressed` event, it gets fired only on mouse right click.

Comment: For WinUI3 and UWP, the `PointerDeviceType` is `Microsoft.UI.Input.PointerDeviceType.Mouse`

Answer (score 3):

You can use the following event to determine what pointer is used and what button is pressed.

```
private void Target_PointerMoved(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Windows.UI.Xaml.Input.Pointer ptr = e.Pointer;
    Windows.UI.Input.PointerPoint ptrPt = e.GetCurrentPoint(Target);

    if (ptrPt.Properties.IsLeftButtonPressed)
    {
        //Do stuff
    }
    if (ptrPt.Properties.IsRightButtonPressed)
    {
        //Do stuff
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Working on a UWP project and previous answers like
Properties.IsLeftButtonPressed/IsRightButtonPressed did not work for me. Those values are always false. I realized during the Debugging that Properties.PointerUpdateKind  was changing according to mouse button. Here is the result which worked for me:

```
var properties = e.GetCurrentPoint(this).Properties;
if (properties.PointerUpdateKind == Windows.UI.Input.PointerUpdateKind.LeftButtonReleased)
{

}
else if (properties.PointerUpdateKind == Windows.UI.Input.PointerUpdateKind.RightButtonReleased)
{

}
else if (properties.PointerUpdateKind == Windows.UI.Input.PointerUpdateKind.MiddleButtonReleased)
{

}
```

There are more options in PointerUpdateKind like ButtonPressed varities of the ones in the example and XButton varities e.g. XButton1Pressed, XButton2Released etc.

Comment: This applied to me, because I was using the `PointerReleased` event instead of the `PointerPressed` event that other answers use.