# How to determine which event called a handler when multiple events are assigned to it?

Tags: c#, xaml, winui

Lets say I assign one handler to two events like this:

```
<Canvas PointerPressed="Handler" PointerMoved="Handler"/>
```

And I have the Handler as:

```
void Handler(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e) {
    /*
     
    */
}
```

How do I know from inside Handler which particular event (PointerMoved or PointerPressed) triggered it ?

Comment: Aside: Most people would use separate handlers for these essentially different events, even though they are compatible in terms of arguments.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError Sure, other than being curious as to whether its possible at all, I think its much more elegant to have code for certain tasks such as drawing a stroke using the mouse onto a canvas unified inside a single function rather than having three separate functions and tying them together using xaml.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second parameter `EventArgs` should have a type corresponding to the particular event the handler is attached to. Therefore, you can determine which event an eventhandler belongs to just by looking at the type of the second parameter.

The `EventHandler` is in reality a delegate (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46824524/event-vs-eventhandler)). Your handler method signature ***has to match*** (including the type of the parameters) with that delegate's signature, <s>so I don't think you can subcribe to `PointerMoved` and `PointerPressed` events with `void Handler(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)` in the first place.</s>

If you are trying to figure out to which event a particular handler is called from between two `EventHandlers` of the same type, then your best bet is to look at the first parameter `sender`. As the name implies, this is a reference to the object that raised the event itself.

---

UPDATE: Sorry, I didn't realize both events do indeed [use the same type PointerRoutedEventArgs](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/winrt-api/blob/docs/windows.ui.xaml.input/pointerroutedeventargs.md):

> The static PointerPoint methods, GetCurrentPoint and GetIntermediatePoints, always use the context of the app. The PointerRoutedEventArgs event data class is used for these events:
>
> PointerPressed, PointerCanceled, PointerCaptureLost, PointerEntered,  PointerExited, PointerMoved, PointerReleased, PointerWheelChanged.

so it's not an option for you to look at the type of the EventArgs argument. As another user said in the comments, it's strange to use the same handler for different events in the first place. In such case, you'd probably need to go case by case, and see what properties of `PointedRouterEventArgs` are relevant to each of the possible events. For example, as shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13905001/6292693), you could check the properties `IsRightButtonPressed` and `IsLeftButtonPressed` of `e.GetCurrentPoint(this)` to determine if the raised event was a `PointerPressed` or a different one. And the same idea with other properties in the EventArgs parameter particularly relevant to `PointerMoved`:

```
void MainPage_PointerPressed(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // Check for input device
    if (e.Pointer.PointerDeviceType == Windows.Devices.Input.PointerDeviceType.Mouse)
    {
        var properties = e.GetCurrentPoint(this).Properties;
        if (properties.IsLeftButtonPressed)
        {
            // Left button pressed
        }
        else if (properties.IsRightButtonPressed)
        {
            // Right button pressed
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I am able to get the handler to work for both the events, but `e.GetType()` merely gives `Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Input.PointerRoutedEventArgs`

Comment: @AjaykrishnanR see the update please.